# How to use new class wiith media player in main activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create new class, becouse I will have there many of sound file, but I don't know how to use it in main ativity. Here is my example code of sound.java:

```
package app.damian.komunikat_v1;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class sound extends MainActivity{

final MediaPlayer sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.miau);
final MediaPlayer sound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.lol);

}
```

And now i'm trying to use sound1.start(); in main activity, but i don't know how. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
This is my MainActivity.java:
      this is my MainActivity.java:

```
   package app.damian.komunikat_v1;

  import android.media.MediaPlayer;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button guzik = findViewById(R.id.button);
    final MediaPlayer sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.miau);

    guzik.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            sound1.start();

        };
    });
  }
 }
```

Comment: You don't create multiple `MediaPlayer` . Create a single `MediaPlayer` and change its data source at runtime .

Comment: In this page you can find a complete tutorial guide and an example code:
[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm)

Comment: Note that when you extend `AppCompatActivity`, you create a new screen in your app. So you now have two screens `MainActivity` and `sound`. Is this what you really want?

Comment: ADM i don't know what do you mean. how exacly should i do it and how to use it in main activity?
Code-Apprentice actually, I did not want it

Comment: On this page is an example of using MediaPlayer in MainActivity. But i'm trying to create new class where i will have list of sounds, and then i have to know how to play some of sounds from the list in main activity

Comment: So as Code-Apprentice said above when you extend AppCompatActivity, you create a new screen in your app. So you now have two screens MainActivity and sound. If you want to play the sounds in MainActivity it is no need to make to activities. For the second one only make a class.

Comment: If you want to call a variable from other activity, you should change it as static and call it like this: MainActivity.sound1.start();

Comment: i change my class  like this: 
package app.damian.komunikat_v1;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;


public class sound  extends MainActivity{

    final  MediaPlayer sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.miau);
    final  MediaPlayer sound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.lol);

}
but how to change it as static? becouse i never done this before

Comment: add `static` after `final` and in MainActivity use `Sound.sound1.start();`

Comment: but when i add static after final i have error: app.damian.komunikat_v1.sound.this' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: I need the complete code to find the problem.

Comment: i edited my post to add my ActivityMain.java. activity_main.xml have only one button.

Comment: when i add static after final in sound class i have this error app.damian.komunikat_v1.sound.this' cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score -1):

I found a different solution. Instead of creating new class with list of sound file, I had created an array of sounds in  main activity class.